# CGImageRef not found when binding a static library to Xamarin.iOS

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios, mono, core-graphics, static-libraries

I am trying to bind some *.framework library which (among others) uses `CoreGraphics`.
So, the code generated by Sharpie is as follows:

```
    // +(CGImageRef)rotateCGImage:(CGImageRef)image byRadians:(double)radians;
    [Static]
    [Export ("rotateCGImage:byRadians:")]
    unsafe CGImageRef* RotateCGImage (CGImageRef* image, double radians);
```

However, when trying to build it, I receive error message like "CGImageRef could not be found".
Also, I can't find corresponding class in the list of members of `CoreGraphics` in `Assembly Explorer`.
(Same way as `using CoreGraphics;` doesn't help.)

It looks like this class (or struct) is just not supported by Mono: I just can't find it in regular iOS project libraries neither.

And actually, there is a number of similar "ref-like" classes which are missed: `CMSampleBufferRef` from `Core Media`, `CVImageBufferRef` from `Core Video` etc.

So, how can I handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've found out (and one of the approaches Xamarin team uses inside of their framework), the solution is as follows:

```
    static extern CGImagePixelFormatInfo CGImageGetPixelFormatInfo (/* __nullable CGImageRef */ IntPtr handle);

    static extern IntPtr /* CFStringRef */ CGImageGetUTType (/* __nullable CGImageRef* */ IntPtr image);
```

So, because of C# managed architecture, there are no explicit pointers to implement, that's why they just didn't create any *Ref-like classes across Mono.

The only thing to point here is that they pass `IntPtr` for both cases: `CGImageRef` and `CGImageRef*`, which has sense of course. However, the trick is in passing the CGImage pointer correctly inside of calling method, because in first case it must be this:

```
    image == null ? IntPtr.Zero : image.Handle
```

so, passing a pointer of the CGImage. But in second case it must be a pointer to Handle, I assume.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the solution in [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/62071/xamarin-binding-project-build-error):

`CGImageRef` doesn't exist in Xamarin. In Obj-C, `CGImageRef` is just a pointer to `CGImage`, so I would think you could just change all of those `CGImageRef` to `CGImage`.

I think it should be something like this:

```
[Static]
[Export("rotateCGImage:byRadians:")]
unsafe CGImage RotateCGImage(CGImage image, double radians);
```

The same to other "`...Ref`" in your project.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for replying, but I've already found out something and just posted the answer. Plus, I am not sure your approach would actually work. You didn't see to test it. As this approach would allow to compile, but doesn't seem like it would work, because Obj-C library expects a pointer to that object instead of actually CGImage, which is even struct, so Native code just would fail (if no crash). And not mentioning that `CGImage*` is definitely not equal to `CGImage`.

Comment: Also, the answer in the link doesn't indicate final success. It looks like the guy was able to compile it, but the link doesn't have an accepted answer neither, so that approach rather would not work.

Comment: @Agat Yeah, I did not do a test. You can mark your solution which can help more people with same problem:).